# Integrated ios app with azure b2c getting scheme does not have a registered handler error

Tags: objective-c, azure, azure-active-directory, devops, azure-ad-b2c

I am going to Integrate ios app which is written in objective-C with Azure B2C. But when I am running user flow for testing getting the error `scheme does not have a registered handler`. And even when I am trying to login into app I don't get any error but still not able to login the redirect URL is not working.

The bundle Id I am passing - `com.bacd.mobilexyz`

My redirect URL - `msauth.com.bacd.mobilexyz://auth`

Can anyone please look into this and let me know if I missed any steps or any configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed that issue on my own.

The redirect URL which we were using was not correct. So make changes in that and final url is - `msauth.com.bacd.mobilexyz://auth/redirect`.

And we add this in desktop and mobile app platform instead of ios/app.